# Does deleting messages in a group chat delete them for everyone else?

Tags: iphone, messages

I wasn’t thinking and sent some messages and pictures to the wrong group chat. I have iOS 16, and I think most everyone else does on it. I didn’t see unsend, so I just deleted them.

The group chat I sent them to isn’t very active, so I wondered if once they open it, there would be nothing there. I heard that it most likely will still show up for them, but I was hoping they wouldn’t. Does anyone know if they will see them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wasn’t thinking and sent some messages and pictures to the wrong group chat… I just deleted them.… Does anyone know if they will see them?

#### Unfortunately, they will see (or have already) those messages.

Deleting a message only affects the messages on *your* device, not your recipients.   You need to use unsend or edit (iOS 16 and later).  Per Apple Support: [Deleting Messages on iPhone](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/delete-messages-iph2c9c4bfcb/ios):

> Note: Deleting messages changes only your own Messages conversations, not those of your recipients. To retract a message you sent accidentally, use undo send instead.

Even if you were to try and [unsend your message](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/unsend-and-edit-messages-iphe67195653/16.0/ios/16.0), you only have two minutes to do so and 15 minutes in which to edit.  As these limits have undoubtedly passed, those messages were delivered. Please note that SMS (non-iMessage) messages cannot be unsent nor edited; they’re delivered immediately.