# How do I make it so that the other person can't see an old text that I sent to them on imessage?

Tags: ios, caller-id

I texted a rude message to someone three years ago. They didn't have my number, so it just showed up as my number with no name attached. Now I need to call this person, but I don't want them to see that I texted them that. Once I call them and they know it is my number, they will be able to go back and see that I texted that to them.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can unsend a message through Messages for about 120 seconds after you send it and edit it for a few more minutes.

[Here are certain conditions that allow you use this feature](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/457537/119271). Unfortunately, none apply here (i.e. SMS messages cannot be undone no matter what).

That said, you’re probably making this a bigger issue than it needs to be.  If the recipient uses the phone for code notifications etc., your unfortunate post is buried so deep it’s not likely to be seen.  If all else fails, claim a mistaken recipient

Comment: One of the conditions for unsending an iMessage is that you have to do it within two minutes of sending.

Comment: I note that fact in the linked post.